# Allocating memory for two concatenated strings

Tags: c, string-concatenation

Is this a right way to allocate memory in order to store two concatenated strings?

```
size_t len1 = strlen(first);
size_t len2 = strlen(second);

char * s = malloc(len1 + len2 + 2);
```

or should I use `malloc(len1 + len2 + 1)`?

Comment: You only need to use `len1 + len2 + 1`; you will 'waste' a whole byte if you use `2` (but the memory manager might allocate as many as 15 extra bytes anyway, so you probably won't notice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at what's necessary to store a string:

- one byte per character (assuming non-wide chars)
- one trailing NUL byte (`'\0'`, or just `0`)

That makes it `strlen(first) + strlen(second) + 1`:

```
char *s = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
char * s = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1); // 1 more space for \0
```

allocating one more space (byte) for `NUL` terminator.