# Appending a string to another in C

Tags: c, string-concatenation

Does this implementation make any sense to you? I'm trying to write a function that will concatenate two strings and can be called as `appendstr(&dest, "xyz");`
I'm not sure at all if is a good practice what I'm doing here, reallocating the space for `newptr` over `origptr` and then free it and make it equal to `newptr`.

```
void *appendstr(char **origptr, const char *strdata)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(*origptr);
    size_t len2 = strlen(strdata);
    char *newptr = realloc(*origptr, len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (newptr != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(newptr + len1, strdata, len2 + 1);
        free(*origptr);
        *origptr = newptr;
    }
    return newptr;
}
```

All I'm trying to do is to not change anything in `*origptr` until I'm sure that there is no problem with the memory allocation and only then, do the concatenation.
Also, another concern is if I'm allocating exactly the amount of memory that I need.

Comment: Don't need to free(*origptr). realloc() does that if newptr is different from origptr.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use strcat(...)?  [See this post.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix does realloc free origptr even if the memory allocation fails?

Comment: If `realloc()` cannot allocate the new space, it returns NULL and the original pointer is still valid, but with no extra space.

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas: Yes, there are good reasons not to use `strcat()`, notably that it has to rescan the first `len1` bytes of the reallocated space to find the null that the code already knows is at `newptr + len1`. Using `memcpy()` saves that rescan.

Comment: Tip: if you intend to concatenate many times, it's probably better to always round to the next power of two, to make the approach to the final size O(log N).

Comment: See also [Allocating memory for two concatenated strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720459/allocating-memory-for-two-concatenated-strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough. It's just your code without the `free()`

```
void *appendstr(char **origptr, const char *strdata)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(*origptr);
    size_t len2 = strlen(strdata);
    char *newptr = realloc(*origptr, len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (newptr != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(newptr + len1, strdata, len2 + 1);
        *origptr = newptr;
    }
    return newptr;
}
```

Returns `NULL` if it couldn't concatenate the strings, and `*origptr` is not changed. Otherwise, it returns the (possibly new) allocated pointer with data concatenated. `*origptr` then will have the same value as the returned value.

`memcpy()` instead of `strcat()` because `strcat()` needs to know where the string ends by calling `strlen()` internally (or doing its own version of `strlen()` ). As anyway you call `strlen()` because you need the length of the string to calculate the amount of memory to allocate, you can use `memcpy()` to directly copy the second string right after the first one, skipping an implicit second call to `strlen()` if were using `strcat()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Should I use memmove instead of memcpy?

Comment: About `memcpy()` vs `memmove()`, read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove

Comment: Is there any way that I can get a memory overrun with this implementation, maybe by getting a second parameter that is not null terminated? If it is posible, how could I fix this?

Comment: I think that would be a topic for another question ;)  Of course you will get into serious problems if the second string is not null terminated. For start, the strlen() call may segfault.